# Optimizing ORDER BY on join two large tables

Tags: mysql

Our systems have two tables: user_posts (post) & user_post_like_counts (count of likes).
I implemented a function to sort posts (asc/desc) by count likes.

Problem is: when data tables are large about 2 millions records. it take long time (**2 minutes**) to perform the sql.

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_posts.*, `user_post_like_counts`.total_count
FROM `user_posts`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `user_post_like_counts` ON `user_post_like_counts`.`user_post_id` = `user_posts`.`id`
WHERE `user_posts`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
       AND `user_posts`.`created_at` <= '2017-04-24 01:47:00'
ORDER BY `user_post_like_counts`.total_count DESC
LIMIT 50
OFFSET 0;
```

If I **remove** the *order by* the above sql just take **less than 1 second** to perform.

This is EXPLAIN for this sql query.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBK4j.png

I really appreciate any help. 
Thanks

Comment: MySql <> Sql Server.

Comment: since you are using paging,you hv to use order by.I think problem is distinct.why use distinct.wht kind if relation between 2 tables.

Comment: What indexes do you have on user_post_like_counts table and what fields do they include?

Comment: Thanks @KumarHarsh . I have just removed distinct.  The time perform the above sql about  more than 1 minute.  can we optimize to several seconds?

Comment: @Shadow I am already index *total_count* & *user_post_id* in **user_post_like_counts**

Comment: That `ORDER BY` clause is going to be a problem. You really can't index on both `created_at` and `total_count`, there's too much cardinality on those. Maybe if you create a new table with *only* the data that's in scope based on `created_at` and `deleted_at`, then index on `total_count` it'll be super quick. Most of the heavy filtering is already done in advance. Update that once a day or whatever as necessary.

Comment: @tadman total_count and created at are in different tables, therefore you can use separate indexes on them. MySQL can use 1 index per table in a query

Comment: @Shadow It can't use a `total_count` index if you've joined against `user_post_id` already. You'd need both columns in an index.

Comment: @tadman based on the OP's comment above, that's the case.

Answer (score 2):

i) you cannot remove order by since you hv to use paging,which is good

ii) Remove distinct

iii) Remove "*" and use only selected column name instead

iii)Hope `user_post_like_counts`.`user_post_id` and `user_posts`.`id` both are CI.

iv) since total_count will always be order by desc,make it NCI and order by desc in index level itself

v) If you get almost all records(80%) by using `deleted_at` IS NULL then no need of creating index on deleted table.

vi) Since post table contain lot of records and is most important table.
Don't keep deleted record on same table.create seperate history table.
This is one important factor

vii) So i think create NCI on created_at with covering index.inlude those columns of post table.